# How to get datetimepicker to work

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I Have a excel sheet with dates that I want to use datetimepicker with (only date needed).  I just want to click on datetimepicker, choose a date and it must show me the info in my data grid view.  this is my button code.

I have a txt box that I have tried, but cannot get the date, I have now put a datetimepicker box, but cannot get ii to work.

any help on this.

Here are my main code

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Tapes_info
Private dtGlobal As New DataTable


Private Sub Tapes_info_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dtGlobal.Clear()
    Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim Builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With {.DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Backuptapes.xls"), .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"}
        Builder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0; IMEX=1;HDR=No;")
        cn.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString
        cn.Open()
        Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 5130 F1 As Tapes, F2 As Containere, F3 as ContainerRef, F4 as DateOut FROM [Tapese$]"
            Dim dr As System.Data.IDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dtGlobal.Load(dr)
            LstTape.DisplayMember = "Tapes"
            LstTape.DataSource = dtGlobal
            txtContainer.DataBindings.Add("Text", dtGlobal, "Containere")
            txtContainerRef.DataBindings.Add("Text", dtGlobal, "ContainerRef")
            txtDateOut.DataBindings.Add("Text", dtGlobal, "Dateout")

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Here is my button code, I want to display any date that I want.

```
Private Sub BtnSearchDateOut_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As     System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSearchDateOut.Click

For i As Integer = 0 To dtGlobal.Rows.Count - 1
    If IsDBNull(dtGlobal.Rows(i)("Dateout")) Then
        dtGlobal.Rows(i)("Dateout") = ""
    End If
Next

Dim query = From item In dtGlobal.AsEnumerable() Where item.Field(Of String)("Dateout").StartsWith(txtSearchDateOut.Text) Select item
If query.Count > 0 Then
    Dim newDT As DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable()

    MsgBox(newDT.Rows.Count.ToString() & " Date out found.")

    Dim frm As New Form()
    Dim dgv As New DataGridView()
    dgv.DataSource = newDT
    dgv.Refresh()
    frm.Controls.Add(dgv)
    dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    frm.Size = New Size(1400, 700)
    frm.Show()

Else
    MsgBox("There is no Date for this found.") 'message
End If
```

Comment: the program I am using is vb.net 2010

Comment: then you should tag the language in question. Let me do it for you. you won't get answers otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're using the date to filter the results but you'll want to start by getting the date from the dateTimePicker; like this: `Dim dt As Date = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value` Then you can use `dt.date` as the input for filtering.